# SharePoint 2010 web analytics custom reports and alerts are not sending

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, web-analytics

I have a couple of custom reports that I would like to have emailed to me using the SharePoint Web Analytics Custom Reports and Alerts. They have been running for the past week, and when I look in the Workflow History, I see the outcome saying:

> Email sent but reports with no data were not attached.

That's fine that they didn't attach any reports, but I'm not even getting an email at all! The same goes with the alerts. I have a dummy alert that just should alert me if the site collection has a hit count > 0, but I don't get any alert for that either.

I have checked to see if emails work. Because if I create a list alert, I do get the confirmation email. I just don't get any emails from the Analytics workflows.

I'm not sure if it matters or not, but I'm using SharePoint Online from Office365.

Comment: Are you receiving other emails like alerts from lists, doc lib etc?

Comment: Yes, it's only the custom reports that are not emailing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's an environment issue. Our sites have usage logging turned off, and judging by various forums, you cannot turn it on in SharePoint Online. Looks like we will be checking out some third party providers.